# Particles system radiating from a single point - trying to recreate the Up baloon scene

Tags: modeling, particles

So essentially trying to recreate the Up-balloon scene but in doing so just experimenting with different blender techniques.

So far:

1. Created 4 baloons (bottom left) with rigid body
2. created larger baloon and added particle system x 5000 in volume etc.
3. Played with phase / rotation etc a little
4. Converted to "instance" or something to separate out the individual objects
5. Played animation to allow balloons to bounce away from eachother.

However, what i now need and can't do (and probably need to start again) is to get the ropes from each baloon to an origin / another object. And in doing so maybe have the baloons a little more "radiating" from that single point.

ANy ideas? many thanks

[image]